# Check if a item in LocalStorage is null and isint changing backgrounds

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, background, local-storage

I made a page of configurations that when i press a button it changes the background, to a color or to a image, i created the localStorages img,and color, my problem is that when they arent null at the same time, instead of the background going for image it goes for making the background with the "color", the code i am trying is this:

```
  if (localStorage.getItem("Color") === null) { //if Color is null
    if (localStorage.getItem("img") === null) {// And Image too
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('css/Images/Instruments/pexels-pixabay-459797.jpg')"; // a image appear in the background
    } else { // else if Color is null but img isint
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem("img"); //load the image in the background
    }
// THIS IS My problem: i dont know how to check if both arent null
    if(localStorage.getItem("Color") !== 'null' localStorage.getItem("img") !== 'null'){ //If Both arent null
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem("img"); // load the Image not the background
    }
  }};
```

Comment: And seriously, checking for null isn't something to ask on StackOverflow, this is a serious site

Comment: What do you think this line will do: ```if(localStorage.getItem("Color") !== 'null' localStorage.getItem("img") !== 'null'){```

Comment: Ive tried that, didnt worked in !== null

Comment: So you've never done logical operations before? how can you check multiple expressions not that way though

Comment: yeah, im just not so good at it kk still learning javascript, i started in another language.

Comment: And how do you do that in the language you're good at? Those are basics

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: in the other language there isnt the localStorage, so like this localStorage im still trying to master with the documentations made by Mozilla. But it would be using !==, the language i was using was a librarie for java that made java look like javascript but much much easier

Comment: I already know about those, and ive already used them but as i said !== wasnt working for me, i found out that since localStorage items are strings it cant be like null if it exists just without an "text/command" in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the logical operator &&, like this:

```
if (!localStorage.getItem('color') {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('img') {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("your image url")';
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('img');
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem('color') && localStorage.getItem('img') {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem('img');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just had to add some ")" but it worked just fine! wow.